# jQuery: tablesorter plugin, disabling sorting on some columns

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm trying to disable sorting of one column in my 3 col table. Following the docs I came up with this:

```
   $('table.sortable').tablesorter( 
     {sortList: [[0,0], [0,0], [0,0]], textExtraction: myTextExtraction}, 
     {headers: {0:{sorter:true}, 1:{sorter:true}, 2:{sorter:false}}}
   );
```

Official docs [here](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-options-headers.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is almost correct. Your textExtraction option needs to be in its own {}, and you don't need to specify the default header options. Try this:

```
$('table.sortable').tablesorter( 
    { sortList: [[0,0], [0,0], [0,0]] }, 
    { textExtraction: myTextExtraction}, 
    { headers: { 2:{sorter:false} } }
);
```