# jQuery tablesorter .addClass("sorter-false") not disabling sort

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm using Mottie's forked version of tablesorter(v2.7.11). When I initially set a column with class="sorter-false" it works correctly and disables the sort for that column. 
However, I want to be able to do this when a particular type of row is added..i.e disable some cols for sorting.  I've tried the following - it adds the correct class but the cols are still sortable. I presume I need the update call after adding the class..but do I need to do anything else?
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
function disableColsFromSortForNewAnimal() {
    $("#thSex").addClass("sorter-false"); 
    $("#thDOB").addClass("sorter-false"); 
    $("#thBreed").addClass("sorter-false"); 
    var resort = false;
    $("#animalsInTestTable").trigger("update", [resort]); 

}
```

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015320/jquery-tablesorter-plugin-disabling-sorting-on-some-columns

Comment: I tried something similar using the following but the cols are still sortable..$("#animalsInTestTable").tablesorter({
      widgets: ['zebra'],
      headers: { 3:{sorter:false},
                 4:{sorter:false},
                 5:{sorter:false} } 
  });

Comment: Side note: you combine multiple ids/classes by using comma: `$("#thSex, #thDOB, #thBreed").addClass("sorter-false");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I'll fix this problem in the next update, so all you'll need to do is add/remove the class and update the table; but for now, use this code to disable a column ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/478/)):

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.tablesorter-header:eq(1)')
        .addClass('sorter-false')[0].sortDisabled = true;
    $('table').trigger('update');
});
```

So your function will become:

```
function disableColsFromSortForNewAnimal() {
    $("#thSex").addClass("sorter-false")[0].sortDisabled = true; 
    $("#thDOB").addClass("sorter-false")[0].sortDisabled = true; 
    $("#thBreed").addClass("sorter-false")[0].sortDisabled = true; 
    $("#animalsInTestTable").trigger("update", false); 
}
```