# how to block sorting a single column of a table in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I generated a table in jquery with 3 columns: number, name, turnover. like this :

```
 $(".tab").append("<tr><td>+ index + "</td><td>+ name + "</td><td>+ turnover + "</td></tr>);
```

and I sort the 3rd column with the "tablesorter".

```
$(".tab").tablesorter({ 
             // sort on the seconde column , desc asc 
              sortList: [[2,-1]] 
        });
```

the problem is that I want my first column "index" does not change, because it shows just number from 1 to 7 but when I do the sorting on the 3rd column my first column also changes.I would like some ideas to solve this problem thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849558/sort-only-one-column-with-jquery-and-tablesorter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942974/how-to-disable-sorting-on-column-in-jquery-tablesorter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015320/jquery-tablesorter-plugin-disabling-sorting-on-some-columns

Comment: even adding the ` headers: {
      0: {
        sorter: false
       }} ` my index changes according to my sort on the turnover column

Comment: I want my index column does not change in any case .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I scanned through the docs and it doesn't look like you can do exactly what you want natively. However, it looks like you can hack together a solution by using [the triggers provided by the library](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-triggers.html). I would do something like this (borrowing some code from the example at the link):

```
$(function(){

  // call the tablesorter plugin, the magic happens in the markup    
  $("table")
    .tablesorter({
      theme: 'blue',
      showProcessing : true
    })    
    .bind("sortEnd",function(e, t){
      $("td.index-column").each(function(index){
          $(this).text(index + 1);
      });
    });    
});
```

Basically, you're adding an event handler that fires when the table is done sorting. At that point, it iterates through each td element that has the class "index-column" (you'd have to assign that class when generating the table - this refers to the values in your index column). Then it sets the text of that element to the index + 1 of the loop (so on the first iteration, 0, set the text of the first matched element to the 1, etc.)